# WP redirect in late action

Tags: wordpress, hook

So I hooked into simple action after some point in plugin

```
function redirect_on_complete($user_id, $lesson_id) {

    $next_prev_lessons = sensei_get_prev_next_lessons($lesson_id);

    if ( !empty($next_prev_lessons['next_lesson']) ) {
        wp_redirect( get_permalink($next_prev_lessons['next_lesson']) );
    }

}
add_action('sensei_user_lesson_end','redirect_on_complete',10,2);
```

How can i implement redirection here? sensei_user_lesson_end is firing to late when some content is alraedy loaded...

I would like to do this without Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No way to do this here, only using JS redirection, so what I have done is opened HTML and inserted JS redirect.